# Estimating Standard Deviation with only Linear Calculations

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, standard-deviation, gaussian-process, point-estimation

I have an input list of numbers which are assumed to be drawn from an underlying Gaussian distribution. I need to find the mean and standard deviation of the dataset. The code that I am working with (which somebody else wrote originally) has the following method to estimate the mean and standard deviation. Of particular note is that it does not involve squaring of any term unlike calculating a typical standard deviation.

- My input is 501 bins of numbers.
- The input list is sorted and 50 bins are removed from the tails on both sides, thereby producing a sorted list of 401 bins.
- The mean of the 501 bins is estimated to be the mean of the 401 bins.
- The standard deviation is calculated as follows:

$$
\sigma = \frac{5.22}{401} \sum_{i=0}^{400} (s_i - \mu) \frac{i}{400}
$$

Like I pointed out earlier, this does not involve any quadratic operation so is faster than calculating the proper standard deviation. I tested the accuracy of this approximation by producing 10,000 random Gaussian distributions (with mean $\in [-100, 100]$ and standard deviation $\in [0, 100]$) and estimating the standard deviation using this method. The result is the following histogram which shows the percentage error in the estimation of the standard deviation. As can be seen, the estimation produces error that's usually less than 10% which is good enough for my purpose.

[image: Percentage error in estimation of standard deviation.]

My question is: where does that approximation of standard deviation come from? I'm assuming the 400 and 401 just reflect the number of bins but other than that I don't understand why calculating the mean deviation times some normalization should be more or less equal to the standard deviation. Additionally, I do not understand where the factor 5.22 comes from.

EDIT: $\mu$ is the estimated mean (estimated from the 401 bins) and $s_i$ is the number in the $i$th bin (out of 401 bins).

Comment: What are $\mu$ and $s_i$?

Comment: $\mu$ is the estimated mean (estimated from the 401 bins) and $s_i$ is the number in the i-th bin (out of 401 bins).

Comment: squaring is simply a multiplication (unless your programmer is calling a power function that relies on exponentiation and logs or something odd like that). You have multiplications in this calculation, so you're not really saving on that. Sorting then calculating that  would generally be slower than just calculating the variance efficiently. [But in any case sorting the bins sounds odd -- how are the bins not already sorted?]

Comment: It was my guess that the approximation was used for efficiency purpose so maybe there is some other reason why the programmer chose to use it. The bins are not sorted because they represent power in each bin of a (very noisy) signal.